# does nodejs prevent directory/path traversal by default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

Expressjs's "express.static()" prevents directory/path traversal by default but I thought Nodejs does not have any protection towards directory/path traversal by default?? Recently trying to learn some web development security(directory/path traversal) and I created this:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url === "/") {
      fs.readFile("./public/index.html", "UTF-8", function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
        res.end(data);
      });
    } else {
      if (req.url === "/favicon.ico") {
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "image/ico" });
        res.end("404 file not found");
      } else {  
        fs.readFile(req.url, "utf8", function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
          res.end(data);
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .listen(3000);

console.log("The server is running on port 3000");
```

to simulate directory/path traversal security vulnerability but I tried to use "../../../secret.txt" and when I check "req.url", it shows "/secret.txt" instead of "../../../secret.txt" and I also tried using "%2e" & "%2f", it still doesn't work, I still can't get "secret.txt"

***(My folder Structure)***

```
- node_modules
- public
  - css
    - style.css
  - images
    - dog.jpeg
  - js
    - script.js
  index.html
- package.json
- README.md
- server.js
- secret.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation of express.static [1], which leads to the docs of the serve-static module [2], the directory you provide is the **root** directory, meaning it's intentionally made impossible to access anything outside of it.

> To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.
>
> The function signature is:
>
> express.static(root, [options])
>
> The root argument specifies the root directory from which to serve static assets. For more information on the options argument, see express.static. [3]

[1] https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

[2] https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html#API

[3] https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static

---

Not related, but fyi: the path you're providing to `fs` etc. is **relative to** where the script is called from.

For example, if you call `node server.js` from the root folder of the application, the path `"./public/index.html"` should work fine, but if you're calling it from a different path, it will fail, e.g. `node /home/user/projects/this-project/server.js`.

Thus, you should always join the path with `__dirname`, like so:

```
+const path = require("path");

-fs.readFile("./public/index.html", "UTF-8", function (err, data) {
+fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "./public/index.html"), "UTF-8", function (err, data) {
}
```

this makes the path relative to the directory of the current file you're trying to access it from, which is what you expect.

Comment: yep, if I am using expressjs with "express.static", I can only access files in public folder because "express.static" prevents directory/path traversal, so I can't access anything outside of public folder, but what about nodejs by itself without any frameworks...?with my question, I am trying to creating a server that has directory/path traversal security vulnerability(learning purpose) but I can't seem to create one...

Comment: you are then using the request wrong. I assume you're testing your server with `curl -L localhost:3000/../../secret.txt`. The problem is that the `req.url` gets resolved to "/secret.txt" -- use `req.query` params (`curl -L localhost:3000?path=../../secret`) or `req.body` (you'll need middleware to parse them). Then, once you receive the path, the "vulnerability" will be successfull -- you might as well not bother using the server and just hard-code the path to `fs.readFile`

Comment: got it :), one more question, if I want to prevent this directory/path traversal security vulnerability problem, what is the best way to prevent this kind of problem...I think path.join removes "../" but is this enough...do I need to do any other things? if it were you how would you write your codes to prevent this kind of security issues?(no frameworks just nodejs by itself) :)

Comment: the path utility will not prevent the vulnerability, it's another thing I mentioned to not get confused about. How could one prevent it? Well, if express.static is able to prevent it via locking the directory root and disallowing access to the outside of it, I would just look into express.static' source code and see how they do it.

Comment: I can see them using path.normalize, path.join, regex check but it also uses this "~path.indexOf('\0')", I am not sure what this is/does.....
https://github.com/pillarjs/send/blob/master/index.js#L520
but basically, in general, I just need to make sure that "the data" coming from "front-end/user" does not include any kind of dangerous characters(like remove, "../", "%2e", "%2f", etc... any characters that they can use to traverse back up the directory), am I correct? am I missing anything I should also be aware of that I should also do/implement?

Comment: well, in general, if you're not a security / cryptography expert, it's wisely suggested to not implement it yourself, unless for educational purposes only. Take note; and sadly I don't know the answer to your question -- you'll have to research stuff yourself.

Comment: understood, no worries, you already help me a lot with my previous questions, thank you :)